# Update activity's TextView from EditText value within ListView's item

Tags: android, listview, textview, listadapter

So, I have an activity with a TextView and a ListView with a custom BaseAdapter. This activity looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, every item of the list is a custom layout and the basic idea is: every time the numeric EditText within it changes, the "total" TextView from the activity (which is the sum of the prices of every product) must be updated as well.

I suppose it must somehow be done from the Adapter class, but I don't know how to do it.

My Activity file looks like this (it gets products data from server via "GetCollectionProducts" AsyncTask, where I set the adapter):

```
public class ProductAisleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
ListView productList;
Button participate;

ImageButton search;
EditText searchET;
TextView productsTotal;

Product[] colProducts;
RelativeLayout collectionHeader;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_aisle);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    /* ...
       Irrelevant code to this question 
    */

    productsTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.products_aisle_total);
    productsTotal.setText(
            getResources().getString(
                    R.string.productsTotal,
                    String.valueOf(0.00)
            )
    );

    productList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.products_aisle_list);
    new GetCollectionProducts().execute();
}

private class GetCollectionProducts extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,JSONArray>{

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        /* Irrelevant code to this question */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        /* Irrelevant code to this question */
                productList.setAdapter(
                        new CollectionProductsAdapter(
                                ProductAisleActivity.this,
                                colProducts
                        )
                );
}
}
```

And my Adapter file looks as follows:

```
public class CollectionProductsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ProductAisleActivity.Product[] data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public CollectionProductsAdapter(Context context, ProductAisleActivity.Product[] data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return data[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row_layout, null);
    }

    ProductAisleActivity.Product product = data[i];

    /* ...
       Irrelevant code to this question 
    */

    EditText productQuantity = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.productQuantity);
    productQuantity.setText("0");


    return v;
}

}
```

I'm stuck at this point, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are a number of ways. You could use a TextWatcher to check when things are modified in the EditText and push it to an Observer or something.

Comment: @zgc7009 can you please show me an example or something? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to listen for any changes in the EditText so you can handle things dynamically without explicitly using something like a submit button. You can do this with a TextWatcher.

```
productQuanity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private double originalCost = 0.0;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // Before we change the text, set the originalCost
            // so we can know what the change is after the edit
            originalCost = getCost(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // You don't need to utilize this method
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             // After the change has taken place in the text,
             // get the new cost and calculate the difference
             double newCost = getCost(s.toString());
             double changeInCost = newCost - originalCost;
        }

        private double getCost(String input){
            String count = input.toString();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(count))
                return 0.0;
            else
                return (double) Integer.parseInt(count) * product.getPrice();
        }
    });
```

Now that we have the change in cost, what do we do with it? We need to notify the activity that we have a change. We can do that with an observer, which is fine, but for fun let's use an interface to implement a listener.

Modify your adapter class

```
public class CollectionProductsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public interface CostChangedListener{
        void onCostChanged(double change);
    }

    Context context;
    ProductAisleActivity.Product[] data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null; // THIS SHOULDN'T BE STATIC
    CostChangedListener listener;

    public CollectionProductsAdapter(Context context, ProductAisleActivity.Product[] data, CostChangedListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // The rest of your code
}
```

Now when we update the cost in our TextWatcher we can call

```
if(listener != null)
    listener.onCostChanged(changeInCost);
```

Last, to make sure we utilize this correctly, we will need to pass a listener in our CollectionProductsAdapter constructor

```
productList.setAdapter(new CollectionProductsAdapter(
            ProductAisleActivity.this, colProducts,
            new CostChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCostChanged(double change){
                    double currentTotal = Double.valueOf(productTotal.getText());
                    double newTotal = currentTotal + change;
                    productTotal.setText(String.valueOf(newTotal));
                }));
```

Obviously you may need to tweak some of this to get it to match perfectly, and I haven't tested it so some things might be off a bit, but this should get you going in the right direction. If you have any issue feel free to comment and I will try to help you through it.

**Notes**

1. Do not keep a static reference like you were with your layout inflater
2. It is worth taking a look at the RecyclerView or at least the ViewHolder pattern with an Adapter

Comment: Thank you! I'll test it right now and tell you how it goes!

Comment: Hey! I have two questions. 1) Where do I get the `oldCost` variable value within the `afterTextChanged()` method? It's not declared!
2) Where do I place this `if(listener != null)
    listener.onCostChanged(changeInCost);` ? Thank you!

Comment: @GénessisSánchez that should say `originalCost` not `oldCost`, I have edited it. Thanks for the notice. You place the listener callback in `afterTextChanged()` after you calculate the `changeInCost`.

Comment: Well, I tried it and now, every time I click on the EditText to update its value, it won't write anything in it. Also, it now shows the alphanumeric keyboard instead of the numeric keyboard it used to show since it's a numeric EditText. Any idea about what's happening?

Comment: @GénessisSánchez the `inputType` in your EditText XML controls the type of keyboard that is shown when you click on said EditText. In regards to it not writing anything in the EditText that is certainly weird. Does your logcat show anything?

Comment: Never mind, it's not writing anything due to a bug with the keyboard when shows/hides that resets the EditText field in all ListView items. When I solve it, I'll test your solution again.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a textChangedListener for changing item values as user changes values in EditText.

You can use TextChangedListener here:

```
EditText myEditTextField = new EditText(this);

myEditTextField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

You can perform tasks according to your need. It has 3 methods:

1.beforeTextChanged

2.onTextChanged

3.afterTextChanged

So you can get your task done by the help of "afterTextChanged". You have to simply call your method of calculating price for no. of items when user enters a particular number.And it will show you the price as you want.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems like the answer I was looking for. Nevertheless, I have two questions, the first one:
Where must the TextWatcher be declared? Into the activity file or into the adapter file?

The second one:
If in the adapter file, how can I access to the activity's TextView?

Thank you again!

Comment: You can implement your textWatcher right below your editText declaration.And if you want to implement it in adapter file, then firstly you would have to define the editText in your viewHolder of the adapter and right below of that (in the same viewHolder class), you can implement textWatcher

Comment: onTextChanged will not provide the appropriate answer. onTextChanged provides subsequence edits. afterTextChanged will provide him the full String to calculate against.

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry! That's a big mistake. @zgc7009
Thanx for finding it out.

Comment: No worries, just worth mentioning :)

Comment: I need to apologize. Your answer was technically originally correct, though it is often recommended to wait for afterTextChanged if you plan on using the input in its entirety. CharSequence s in onTextChanged will work though. For some reason I was thinking it only provided the subsequence that was edited.

Comment: No problem. I also think the same that for getting correct and entire input, one would have to wait for making the app working correctly